# Define saturation temperature? other properties in function of P and Quality?

Tags: modelica, temperature, dymola, pressure

I am new in Dymola and I am having some problems to calculate some properties of my working fluid (methane), is there a way to define the saturation temperature, latent heat of vaporization, density, in function of the Pressure and Quality (Q=0 liquid, Q=1vapor) as in this example :

## Saturated vapor enthalpy of Water at 1 atm in J/kg

In [4]: H_V = PropsSI('H','P',101325,'Q',1,'Water'); print(H_V)
2675529.3255007486

## Saturated liquid enthalpy of Water at 1 atm in J/kg

In [5]: H_L = PropsSI('H','P',101325,'Q',0,'Water'); print(H_L)
419057.7330940691

Comment: You might want to try ExternalMedia: https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/ExternalMedia Look for recent issues/comments/branches and try to help out!

Comment: which medium model are you using? Is it a two phase medium?